# Error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(string, object)'

Tags: c#, .net

Getting this Error `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.SetValue(string, object)'` ,I have fetched the value from Registry and trying to update them with new value using below code ,but it is showing me this error ,where i am going wrong?

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtEmailID.Enabled = true;
            string eid = txtEmailID.Text;
            RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot;
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\StudentExam\Protection", true);
            RegistryKey.SetValue("EmailID", eid);//Error at this Line
         }
```

Comment: you have created an instance 'registryKey ' of class RegistryKey. use registryKey instead of  RegistryKey to setvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created an instance of `RegistryKey` class. So its not a static class, but you are trying to use the class as it being a static class.

Just use its object(`registryKey`) that you have initialized earlier and it will be fine.

Therefore, replace

```
RegistryKey.SetValue("EmailID", eid);//Error at this Line
```

with

```
registryKey.SetValue("EmailID", eid);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/79b3xss3.aspx):

> You can define a class as static if you want to guarantee that it can't be instantiated, can't derive from or serve as the base for another type, and can contain only static members.
>
> Because you can't create an instance of a static class, you can't use the `new` keyword to create a variable of the class type. You must access the members of a static class by using the class name itself. For example, if you have a static class that's named `UtilityClass` and that has a public method that's named `MethodA`, you call it as the following example shows:

```
UtilityClass.MethodA();
```

But if the class is not a static class , then you can just call that method as below:

```
UtilityClass utility = new UtilityClass();
utility.MethodA();
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to add to Bhushan Firake's answer that while most of the times using this kind of naming is just fine, you should consider naming your variables in a more meaningful names. that will help you not getting into this kind of trouble, and also in other cases, as for example if you needed 2 `RegistryKey` as to explain what is each variable is used for

Read [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MeaningfulName) for more information on why you should use meaningful names.